# Как добавить progressBar на выполнение задачи?

Tags: c#

Написал программу, которая выводит название всех файлов выбранной папки в txt документ.
Хочу "прикрутить" progressBar на выполнение. Никак не получается это сделать... Помогите пожалуйста. Дымлюсь уже(. Заранее спасибо.

Вот код программы:

```cs
private void Open_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //выбор папки
    FolderBrowserDialog fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        item_textBox.Text = fb.SelectedPath;
}

private void OpenListFileName(string itemList)
{
    //получение названия файлов и вывод их в txt
    timer1.Start();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(itemList);
    FileInfo[] fi = dir.GetFiles();

    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        FileName = "Название",
        DefaultExt = "*.txt",
        Filter = "Текстовый файл|*.txt"
    };

    if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveFile.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName, true))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; ++i)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(fi[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Run_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenListFileName(item_textBox.Text);
}

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value > 100)
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    //else
    //    progressBar1.Value += 1;
}
```

Comment: А что не так было с `progressBar1.Value += 1;`?

Comment: Когда прогрессбар доходит до конца, вываливает ошибка: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Значение '101' недопустимо для 'Value'. 'Value' должно лежать в диапазоне от 'minimum' до 'maximum'.
Имя параметра: Value"
Да и прогрессбар сам по себе работает. Программа давно закончила свою работу.

Comment: Логика программы такая: я нажимаю на кнопку Получить (OpenListFileName). Выбираю папку и в это время должен срабатывать прогрессбар. Ну вообщем простыми словами должен прогресс бар показать окончание действия. А он сам по себе живет.

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите документацию, почитайте примеры https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=windowsdesktop-7.0, выставьте ему `Maximum` равный `fi.Length` и потом дёргайте `PerformStep();` в цикле обработки файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если почитать [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=netframework-4.7.2), то там всё проще, чем вы делаете, не нужно вешать обработку прогресс бара на таймер, вы сами должны его дёргать примерно так, если скрестить пример из документации с вашим кодом:

```cs
    // Display the ProgressBar control.
    pBar1.Visible = true;
    // Set Minimum to 1 to represent the first file being copied.
    pBar1.Minimum = 1;
    // Set Maximum to the total number of files to process.
    pBar1.Maximum = fl.Length;
    // Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
    pBar1.Value = 1;
    // Set the Step property to a value of 1 to represent each file being copied.
    pBar1.Step = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; ++i)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(fi[i].ToString());
        pBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

Больше ничего программировать не нужно. Только положить `progressBar` на форму и назвать его `pBar1`, как в примере из документации. ну или наоборот в коде всё переделать под ваше название этого контрола.

Comment: Все теперь дошло). Спасибо! А почему тогда везде советуют вешать таймер?

Comment: @mygedz Не знаю. Может там производятся какие-то действия, завязанные на ограничение времени выполнения? )  Надо конкретные примеры смотреть )